# pseudo shell script: execute activate_this.py from python3 to switch environments

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, activation

I'm trying to activate virtualenv through a python3 script, so I could switch virtualenvs from the commandline without having to type too much.

I'm trying to do this without starting new shells for each invocation of VE's activate_this.py script.

Is it at all possible to do this via Python?

Something like the following doesn't seem to work when intended to activate the environment from code, then pass control back to Shell?
`exec(open(activate_this_path).read()`

Must I do this in bash to have the VE take effect?

Answer (score 0):

So I've been hitting my head against the wall with this one. Fortunately, I came upon the following:

1. It's not possible to change environment within Python itself (i.e. `source` commands must be ran within shell)
2. The wonderful [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) already does what I wanted - and more.